# Problems cloning an old production Craft CMS project

Tags: craft3

I'm attempting to clone a craft CMS (v3.3.15) project into a new local development environment and as expected, I'm experiencing many dependency issues. For various reasons, including having to replace my original development machine, the production site has gone without any attention for over a year, although it still works perfectly. I'm having issues with the fxp/composer-asset-plugin and several tables although present in the database dump, are not available on the local site (users, entries, assets, etc), templates work fine. My cloning process which used to work is now failing.

I've tried using composer at v1.x and the plugins at the same versions currently running on the server and also tried updating composer to 2.x and updating the plugins to their latest version, however, neither seems to work. I've also tried updating using php craft. I'm obviously missing something major. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked plugin status/compatibility?  It could be that you have plugins that aren't functional with newer Craft versions. Other than that, if you're using `project-config` files, you could try forcibly rebuilding the database using those files, and/or forcibly regenerating them.

Comment: @TammyShipps, you're probably correct. I'm not there yet but making progress. Templates load but users, categories and entries still not being pulled in from the database. I'm in the process of addressing issues identified in the Craft log files and attempting to incrementally advance the Craft CMS version. It's an adventure but I'll get there.